# R: select region on matrix

Tags: r, matrix

Assume `X` is a 5x5 matrix (which represents pixel luminosity from a picture):

[image]

I would like to select the element that fit within a given simple geometrical shape (e.g. square, circle, ovale) superposed to this matrix. In this example I would like to select the elements from the matrix that fall (even slightly) within the ovale.

[image]

Ultimately those elements position would be return into a vector logical vector `elementInOvale` on which I could perform a simple operation such as `X[elementInOvale] <- 0`

[image]

I have the feeling that this is a common problem which has already been solved, I just don't know how to formulate or where to find information about it, and to do with R.

Comment: How do we know where the shape (i.e. the oval) is placed?